# How do I add, edit or manage custom search engines in Opera 15 or higher versions (Chromium-based)?

Tags: browser, opera, search-engines, opera-next

The recently released [Opera 15](http://my.opera.com/desktopteam/blog/2013/07/02/opera-15) is now based on the Chromium engine and now doesn't manage custom search engines like the previous versions.

I found [this method of managing custom search engines](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95653?hl=en) for Chrome but it doesn't work for Opera 15 or higher versions. There is no 'Manage search engines' button in Settings > Search.

**How do I manage custom search engines in Opera 15 or higher versions?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Starting with Version 17 (Developer Preview) Opera includes a Search-Engine Manager, which allows the user to add his own search engines. But the default search engines included with Opera cannot be edited in this way! To edit them use the first part of this answer, Versions 15-16 can also use the second part:

Disabling the default Search Providers (because they take up many keywords I would rather use for other searches - I just left Google with the classical 'g')

To do so, you have to edit the **default_partner_content.json** which is usually found in *C:\Program Files\Opera\resources\*
You can edit it by hand, or just replace it's content with the following:

```
{
  "search_engines": {
    "location": {
      "other": {
        "other": {
          "list": [
            "google_com"
          ],
          "speed_dial_index": 0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "search_engines_flat": {
    "google_com": {
      "name": "Google Search",
      "keyword": "g",
      "favicon_url": "http://www.google.com/favicon.ico",
      "search_url": "https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q={searchTerms}&sourceid=opera&ie={inputEncoding}&oe={outputEncoding}",
      "suggest_url": "http://www.google.com/complete/search?client=opera&q={searchTerms}&ie={inputEncoding}&oe={outputEncoding}",
      "post": false,
      "encoding": "UTF-8",
      "uuid": "FF57F01A-0718-44B7-8A1F-8B15BC33A50B",
      "css_resource": "css/searchstyle_google.css"
    },
  },
  "speed_dials": {
  },
  "speed_dial_folders": {
  },
  "speed_dials_flat": {
  }
}
```

Embedding your custom Search Engines in the **Web Data** File (usually found in *C:\Users\#username#\AppData\Roaming\Opera Software\Opera\* You can edit the **SQLite3** format which is shared by Opera in 2 easy ways: Either install Chrome, create your custom searches and copy the Web Data File over to Opera.

Or edit the File using a free SQLite-Editor like http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitedbrowser/

(You should copy the Web-Data File to your home-folder, so you have full write-access, or opening the file may fail) There you can enter your own search-engines into the **keywords** table - most of the fields should be self-explaining...

Comment: thx :-) I hope it helps, because I didn't find any other page with a solution...

Comment: I just want to note that [Opera 17 developer preview](http://my.opera.com/desktopteam/blog/2013/08/08/opera-17-first-developer-stream-preview) has a search engine manager. Maybe you want to add that to your answer :)

Comment: Of course the path will be different in each version, but for comparison I found it here, for Opera 27: C:\Program Files (x86)\Opera\27.0.1689.54\resources\default_partner_content.json.

Comment: @Nixda and JonofAllTrades: Know the path to *default_partner_content.json* for the Linux version of Opera?

Comment: Unfortunately, some time in the last few weeks Opera was updated and this solution no longer works.  After removing DuckDuckGo from the default_partner_content.json file, Opera reports "At least one file with resources (.pak) is corrupted. Please reinstall Opera." on boot.  Hopefully there's another workaround.

Comment: @galacticninja sorry for late response, but here it is for everyone else as well: `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/resources/default_partner_content.json` though unfortunately, this solution no longer works.

Answer (score 2):

Opera 21 was just released and I found simply deleting the *default_partner_content.json* file from the *C:\Program Files (x86)\Opera{version_number}\resources* directory removed all providers (but Google) from the list. The name of the entry changed from "Google Search" to just "Google", so I would surmise it is some internal "I don't have a default list" default.

Using the *Manage Search Engines* tool, I was able to make new entries for the deleted keywords (y, b, etc.) but was not able to set them as  the default--no *Default* button appears next to them.

Answer (score 0):

On OS X you'll have to edit or remove the file found here:
     /Applications/Opera.app/Contents/Versions/VERSION_NUMBER/Opera Framework.framework/Resources/default_partner_content.json

Replace VERSION_NUMBER as appropriate.

Right click the Opera app and "show packages contents" to browse the files.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac (on 10th Feb 2015), the correct folder is: `~/Library/Application Support/com.operasoftware.Opera`. There you can find some essential files such as Web Data (and Web Data-journal and Preferences).

It is possible to copy custom search engines from Chrome to Opera both in Windows and OSX. In OSX, just first close Chrome and Opera and then copy `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Web Data` (a file) to the equivalent Opera folder already mentioned (rename the old file to something else as a backup).