# Opera 37+ : Remove default search engines

Tags: opera, search-engines

Has anyone found a new way to get rid of the default search engines?

Things have changed again since: [Opera 31: Remove default Search Engines?](https://superuser.com/questions/956087/opera-31-remove-default-search-engines) and so far as I can tell, none of those answers apply any longer.

Version information

- Version: 37.0.2178.41 - Opera is up to date
- Update stream:   Stable
- System:  Windows 10 64-bit (WoW64)

Comment: Based on my [research](http://superuser.com/questions/709209/setting-a-custom-search-engine-as-default-in-opera) the functionality was removed and still does not exist yet in Opera Blink.

Comment: @Ramhound 1) That's a different question about adding a custom search engine as default & 2) That is no longer the case since that was way back in v19 *(2 years ago)* where that research was applicable: http://imgur.com/JRnpQ7p

Comment: Funny at first glance, but when you think about it, it's rude and belittling, and fails to understand that deals with search engines are the lifeblood of browsers with smaller market share. I don't agree either with the path Opera has taken since version 15+, but that's no reason to paint them as an evil corporation trying to trample on users' rights. If you want more of the power-user-targeted customisability that Opera Presto was once renowned for, switch to Vivaldi. -1, as I find this offensive.

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter Both Chrome and Firefox let you do this. It's perfectly reasonable to pre-package them but it's ludicrous to make it impossible to remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Use [Vivaldi](https://vivaldi.com/) instead - basically everything Opera is and more:

- Supports Chrome Extensions
- Allows removal of undesired search engines
- Superior customization

Comment: Interesting find. Does it have a fully portable version ? Does it support Opera's extensions ? Is there a 64-bit version ?

Comment: 1) Portable: https://forum.vivaldi.net/topic/2819/release-an-official-portable-version 2) who cares about opera extensions? - Chrome extensions are supported and there's more/better versions of those 3) 64-bit: https://forum.vivaldi.net/topic/7796/32-vs-64-bit-vivaldi

Comment: Does it have a build it VPN?

Comment: Not built in but you can install free VPN extensions that are Chromium compatible.

Comment: Tried it out, not so snappy as Opera unfortunately..

Answer (score 2):

As of Opera 44, at least one way described for Opera 31 works (still or again?): "[editing the %operaversion%/resources/default_partner_content.json](https://superuser.com/a/1067518)". The linked answer suggests to "set the edited file to be read-only and/or set opera://flags/#first-run-partner-content-update to disabled." I opted for "and". Still have to see what happens with an update, probably we'll have to make some sort of script for the job.

Maybe other answers there work, too, but I did not try them.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens What "relevant" quotes from answers I did not try could I provide?

Comment: I did not realize that links to existing answers elsewhere on stackexchange will be considered bad. Thanks for the hint, then! If this is the risk, I will include a summary of the answer I'm linking to. Seems a bit redundant (especially in this context, referring to an answer to a question this question refers to), but what don't we do for The Rules.